# When i started the npm facing the issue with the android studio with the following error 'The emulator is failing quit before it finished opening'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, npm-install, android-studio-3.0, npm-start

When ever i started the `npm start` in VS code, and the metrobundler got started. The VS code started showing error

> Error: The emulator (Galaxy_Nexus_API_31) quit before it finished opening. You can try starting the emulator manually from the terminal with:

[image]

Also i have wiped the Android Device Manager on Androidstudio app.

[image]

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, how could i overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First try `Wipe Data` & `Cold Boot Now`.
After that open the emulator, and run (in your terminal, cmd)

```
adb devices
```

This will show devices, that are connected, if it shows `offline` it means that the emulator is running but it is not connected.

This is working example, when emulator is running and connected.

[image: Working example]